# Is "if rain wouldn't come," grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality, modal-verbs

I would like to ask if the two following expressions are correct;

> A) If rain wouldn't come, I could go on a picnic.
> B) If rain didn't come, I could go on a picnic.

Answer (score 1):

You need more context to frame the statement. If you mean simply
"If it doesn't rain, I could go on a picnic.",
something you are considering for this afternoon, then that is idiomatic.

Both A and B are set as future-in-past, a consideration you may have had at some past time.

A sounds as if you wanted rain for some reason, but if you didn't get it, then the picnic would be an alternative activity.

Unless there is some particular reason to speak of the *rain coming*, then the simple verb *rain* is more idiomatic.